# How to get the 2nd item in a row of 3?

Tags: php, math, ternary-operator

I have a webpage layout where there are rows of 3. I need to gove the middle item a special css class. How to do that?

```
div [div] div
div [div] div
div [div] div
div [div] div
```

I know with table rows you can get alternating row colors using the ternary operator to detect them:

```
class="<?= $key % 2 == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'"
```

but how to do it for the 2nd in a row of 3?

P.S. I am awful at math, perhaps the answer is quite obvious.

Comment: `class="<?= $key % 3 == 1 ? 'odd' : 'even'"`

Comment: As mark points out, it isn't the ternary operator doing the magic, it's the [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) test for the remainder.

Comment: @MarkBaker if you post that as an answer I will accept. I can't use the css solution because of browser support. I have to support ie7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the divisor for the modulus test to 3 (for every block of 3 rows); and test for a result of 1 (the 2nd entry from offset 0)

```
class="<?= $key % 3 == 1 ? 'odd' : 'even'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to apply a style to the `nth-child`...

```
div:nth-child(3n+2) {
    color: red;
}
```

You can see an example of this on this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kTnsK/).

If you really need to do this in PHP you could use `% 3` instead of 2 and take off 1 to get the offset.

Comment: this is not necessarily css. The tag does not have css